# Haskell libssh2 module throws ERROR_KNOWN_HOSTS

Tags: haskell, ssh, libssh2

I am trying to ssh to my local machine using [`libssh2-hs`](https://github.com/portnov/libssh2-hs/blob/master/libssh2/ssh-client.hs#L12) module. The command i used is,

```
runhaskell ssh-client.hs command sk localhost 22 ls
```

And it throws,

```
ssh-client.hs: ERROR_KNOWN_HOSTS
```

When i run ssh client as,

```
ssh sk@localhost
```

it goes through successfully.

This error message is inadequate.. (or) is there any other haskell ssh library, i can use.

I deleted all host fingerprints in /home/sk/.ssh/known_hosts and it throws `Authentication failure`. And surprisingly, the [cli tool](https://github.com/portnov/libssh2-hs/blob/master/libssh2/ssh-client.hs#L12) is not having any traces of taking a password/privat key argument.